# Error with using lambdas, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to replace method call with lambda expression in Kotlin, but something is wrong and idk what is it.

Here is me code:

```
httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor: (Interceptor.Chain?) -> Response {

})
```

Here is working code without lambdas:

```
httpClient.addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain?): Response {
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation about [lambda syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions).

Comment: This may help you. https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/7asvab/dont_use_lambdas_as_listeners_in_kotlin/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code:

```
httpClient.addInterceptor { chain: Interceptor.Chain? ->
  // return a `Response` here
  TODO()
}
```